# AxonIQ Framework - com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: No converter available

Tags: spring, spring-boot, axon

I am developing Saga Pattern with CQRS AxonIQ and Spring Boot Framework. I am getting the below error when I start `order-service`

Source code here: https://github.com/javaHelper/cqrs-progressive/tree/main/event-sourcing-axon/3.saga-pattern-implementation

Error: -

```
## Saga invoked
order id => 087d8999-be17-49df-b999-52e8008b87b6
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary (file:/Users/prats/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.18/xstream-1.4.18.jar) to field java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.$assertionsDisabled
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2022-07-25 17:40:20.223  WARN 76448 --- [ault-executor-0] o.a.c.gateway.DefaultCommandGateway      : Command 'com.example.demo.commands.CreateInvoiceCommand' resulted in org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandExecutionException(Error while deserializing object)
2022-07-25 17:40:20.240  WARN 76448 --- [agaProcessor]-0] o.a.e.TrackingEventProcessor             : Error occurred. Starting retry mode.

com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: No converter available
---- Debugging information ----
message             : No converter available
type                : java.net.SocketCleanable
converter           : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
message[1]          : Unable to make field jdk.internal.ref.PhantomCleanable jdk.internal.ref.PhantomCleanable.prev accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.ref" to unnamed module @2577a95d
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.DefaultConverterLookup.lookupConverterForType(DefaultConverterLookup.java:88) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream$1.lookupConverterForType(XStream.java:472) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:48) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:87) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeBareItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:94) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeCompleteItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:81) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.ArrayConverter.marshal(ArrayConverter.java:45) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:87) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeBareItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:94) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:66) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeCompleteItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:81) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.marshal(MapConverter.java:79) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:270) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:174) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:262) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:82) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1243) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1232) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:1205) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at org.axonframework.serialization.xml.XStreamSerializer.doSerialize(XStreamSerializer.java:126) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.serialization.AbstractXStreamSerializer.serialize(AbstractXStreamSerializer.java:108) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.jpa.AbstractSagaEntry.<init>(AbstractSagaEntry.java:58) ~[axon-modelling-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.jpa.SagaEntry.<init>(SagaEntry.java:41) ~[axon-modelling-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.jpa.JpaSagaStore.createSagaEntry(JpaSagaStore.java:331) ~[axon-modelling-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.jpa.JpaSagaStore.insertSaga(JpaSagaStore.java:299) ~[axon-modelling-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.AnnotatedSagaRepository.storeSaga(AnnotatedSagaRepository.java:217) ~[axon-modelling-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.AnnotatedSagaRepository.lambda$doCreateInstance$3(AnnotatedSagaRepository.java:139) ~[axon-modelling-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.MessageProcessingContext.notifyHandlers(MessageProcessingContext.java:72) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.BatchingUnitOfWork.lambda$notifyHandlers$2(BatchingUnitOfWork.java:155) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1033) ~[na:na]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.BatchingUnitOfWork.notifyHandlers(BatchingUnitOfWork.java:155) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.AbstractUnitOfWork.changePhase(AbstractUnitOfWork.java:222) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.AbstractUnitOfWork.commitAsRoot(AbstractUnitOfWork.java:83) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.AbstractUnitOfWork.commit(AbstractUnitOfWork.java:71) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.BatchingUnitOfWork.executeWithResult(BatchingUnitOfWork.java:111) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.AbstractEventProcessor.processInUnitOfWork(AbstractEventProcessor.java:159) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processBatch(TrackingEventProcessor.java:462) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processingLoop(TrackingEventProcessor.java:294) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$TrackingSegmentWorker.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1016) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$WorkerLauncher.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1162) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

Axon Framework will serialize your entire Saga class to be able to process the events once they're there. As such, any global fields you place in the Saga will be serialized. The serialized Sagas from there are kept in the `SagaStore. You can read the Reference Guide on [Saga -> Infrastructure](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/sagas/infrastructure) for some more details on this.

Furthermore, Axon Framework uses several layers of `Serializer` you can configure. These layers are "event," "message," and "generic", as you can find [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/serialization#serializer-implementations) in the Reference Guide. By default, the `XStreamSerializer` is used, since it's "reflective nature" ensured that everything could be de-/serialized.

However, with the onset of JDK 17, many classes are shut down from reflective access. I am pretty confident it's this predicament around XStream you're facing. As becomes clear from the exception.

There are roughly two things you can do:

1. Remove the specific class that cannot be serialized. Note that especially services you'd wire in your Saga should be `transient` as those are otherwise de-/serialized for you.
2. Replace the `XStreamSerializer` for the `JacksonSerializer`.

This has made XStream less ideal as the default `Serializer`. Sadly enough, changing this is a breaking change for Axon Framework users, so the Framework still sticks to XStream.

Comment: I'll request you to look at my code and because I am not explicitly `XStreamSerializer` any where. Would be good if you can suggest where to exactly make change in my POC?

Comment: The reference guide shows how to configure the serializer: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/serialization#serializer-implementations

Comment: As stated, Axon takes a reasonable default, which is XStream. 
So it makes sense you've not explicitely set it yourself. Added, at this stage it's not clear to me whether your predicament lies with point 1 or 2. I'd expect an update from your end stating what setup you want to end up with before I expand mine with a conclusive answer.

Comment: After a quick check through your repo, I see that you've wired the `CommandGateway` without making it `transient`. Is provided in my answer, Sagas are entirely serialized. Hence with your current setup, the entire `CommandGateway` is serialized as well. I'd wager the predicament is resolved if you add `transient` to your wired services in the Saga.

Comment: @Steven - Nope its not working for me at all. `@Autowired
 private transient CommandGateway commandGateway;` doesn't solve problem

Comment: Regardless of whether it solves the issue, you definitely should make it `transient` due to the aforementioned reasons. So thanks for doing so.

Comment: Now to the situation, I assume it's the `OrderManagementSaga`, right? It's odd you receive a serialization issue on this while the *only* thing in it is the `CommandGateway`. The only other thing to go on in your stack trace is the `CreateInvoiceCommand`, which also doesn't contain anything exciting. So, not to be pushy, but is the code I see here up to date? https://github.com/javaHelper/cqrs-progressive/blob/main/event-sourcing-axon/3.saga-pattern-implementation/order-service/src/main/java/com/example/demo/sagas/OrderManagementSaga.java

Comment: In my case, the saga serialises to `{}` with Jackson. What might be going on? @steven

Comment: I'm sorry, Alexandre, but we'd need a little more to go on for your scenario. Perhaps you can open another StackOverflow issue for your exact problem case to help you further? I'd be shooting int he dark with your case, as I don't know what your Saga class looks like. If it doesn't have any fields, for example, then serializing to `{}` sounds perfectly valid to me. Or, Jackson is incapable of extracting any of your fields. Who knows! At any note, for more thorough help, I'd suggest making a separate issue, and sharing your (serializer) config and saga implementation.